# Refer to an array element from inside the array itself

Tags: php, arrays

I was writing unit tests for an entity like this:

```
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->getPath() . $this->getName();
    }

    /**
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }
}
```

As you can see the `getUrl()`method returns a string formed of `path`and `name`.

This is the code to test it:

```
class ImageTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * Tests all get and set methods
     */
    public function testImage()
    {
        $resource = new Image();

        $test = array(
            'name' => 'testName.jpg',
            // Set this without the ending slash (/)
            'path' => 'path/to/image',
        );

        $test['url'] = $test['path'] . $test['name'];

        $this->assertEquals($test['name'],       $resource->getName());
        // Check that, when set, a slash (/) is added at the end of the Path
        $this->assertEquals($test['path'] . '/', $resource->getPath());
        $this->assertEquals($test['url'],        $resource->getUrl());
    }
}
```

As you can see, first has to be created the `array`, then it is possibile to set `$test['url']`.

At this point the curiosity because I were writing, instead, something like this:

```
$test = array(
    'name' => 'testName.jpg',
    'path' => 'path/to/image',
    'url'  => $test['path'] . '/' . $test['name']
);
```

But this syntax returns this error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) Tests\Entity\ImageTest::testImage Undefined variable:
>   test

**Maybe is there something like the `self` statement for `Objects`?**

Answer (score 1):

No. The array isn't defined until `$test = array(...);` command completes.

```
$test = array(
    'name' => 'testName.jpg',
    'path' => 'path/to/image',
);

$test['url'] = $test['path'] . '/' . $test['name'];
```

It doesn't look as nice as what you're trying to do, but that's the correct way to do it.